# Matlab freezes at certain files when dicomread is used

Tags: matlab

This problem is bothering me for a long time and I hope that someone is able to help me. I've searched the internet extensively but it seems that im the only one with this problem.

Occasionally when im loading multiple dicom files into Matlab it freezes at a certain file. Im unable to terminate the script and i have to force matlab to shut down. I do not know if this is a bug but i hope that there is a work-around for this because the dicomread does not return an error but freezes Matlab.

More information:

- It happens with multiple datasets from different organisations
- It happens with multiple computers
- Matlab version 2013b/2014a/2014b

I hope that somebody can help me to fix this or find a workaround.

Comment: Could it be that you try to load more things than you r memory can handle?

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Matlab still freezes when i'm loading that single file. This dicom contains one slice of a PET image. The  strange part is that im able to open this file with any dicom viewer without any problems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same problem and I am using Matlab 2014. The same code I have runs fine on Matlab 2012. 
I solved the issue by copying the DICOM library from Matlab 2012 to 2014. If you have a Windows machine, the library in the 2012 version is typically installed at

> C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2012a\toolbox\images\iptformats

The 2014 version is at

> C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2014a\toolbox\images\iptformats

Answer (score 0):

Identical problem here with 3D CT scans. I had hundreds of scans stored as dicom folders (1 file per slice) that I converted to dicom volumes (1 file per entire volume) with compression. 6 of them would trigger a segmentation fault in the dicomparse call inside dicomread, despite I had no problem reading them in other software tools.

Twe easiest walkaround for me was to re-export these dicoms as uncompressed dicom volumes with a different software tool.